# How can I continue adding elements below my Navbar in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, flutter-web, flutter-animation

I build this Navbar in Flutter and this is my code and a screenshot of the result. I want to add different elements below my such as text, images and other things, navbar but when I try to do that, it shows nothing. Can someone tell me how can I solve this? I'm new to Flutter.

```
import 'dart:html';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:color/color.dart';


class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const HomePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<HomePage> createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Stack(
        children: [
          Container(
            width: double.infinity,
          
         color: Colors.grey[900],         
         child: Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
          children: <Widget>[
            SizedBox(
              //height: 150,
             // width: 150,
              child: Image.asset('assets/images/logo.png'),
            ),
             Spacer(),
         Text("Escorts",
         style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white , fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),),
         SizedBox(width: 32,),
         Text("Angenturen & Clubs",
         style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white , fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),),
         SizedBox(width: 32,),
         Text("Inserieren",
         style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white , fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),),
         SizedBox(width: 32,),
         Text("Werben",
         style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white , fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),),
         SizedBox(width: 32,),
         Text("Blog",
         style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white , fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),),
         SizedBox(width: 32,),
         Text("Kontakt",
         style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white , fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),),
         Spacer(),
         Icon(Icons.attach_money, color: Colors.white,),
         SizedBox(width: 20,),
         Icon(Icons.chat, color: Colors.white,),
         SizedBox(width: 20,),
         Icon(Icons.person, color: Colors.white,),
         SizedBox(width: 20,),
         Icon(Icons.search, color: Colors.white,),
         SizedBox(width: 32,),
         
          ],
         ),
        ),
         
        ],
        
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[image: image1]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to put a column widget on top of your stack widget in your code:
something like this:

```
Column(
  children: [
    Stack(children: [
     (your abbBar code)
      .
      .
      .

    ],),
 (your body code)
     .
     .
     .
  ],
);
```

Comment: Ok I did it, now where can I put new text for example below my navbar please? @aminjafari-dev

Comment: You have to add new text, where I wrote (your body code)

Comment: ,
Column(
  children: [
    Stack(children: [
     (your abbBar code)
      .
      .
      .

    ],),
 (your body code)
***new text***
     .
     .
     .
  ],
);
,

Comment: your welcome, i hope u are well

Answer (score -1):

use [BottomNavigationBar](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/BottomNavigationBar-class.html) from flutter , you can edit the icons and texts

Comment: but I'm not trying to add anything in the bottom. I want to add these elements on the body. I'm doing a web application @anas